# Get url of multi images when upload them to Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-storage

can you help me with getting array of URLs while uploading images to firebase?

my imageUrl = [undefined, undefined] when uploading 2 img

```
export const handleUploadProductPhoto = async (files) => {
  const imageUrl = await Promise.all(
    files.map((file) => {
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const uploadTask = firebase
          .storage()
          .ref()
          .child(`your/file/path/${file.name}`)
          .put(file);
        uploadTask.on(
          firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress =
              (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            if (snapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING) {
              console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
            }
          },
          (error) => console.log(error),
          () => {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref
              .getDownloadURL()
              .then((url) => resolve(url));  //I have success here - two urls
          }
        );
      });
    })
  ).then((res) => console.log(res));
};
```

Comment: At first glance the code looks good. So are you saying that this `console.log(res)` at the bottom ends up logging `[undefined, undefined]`?

Comment: I сall handleUploadProductPhoto in my saga in try/catch block and get [undefined,undefined]. I am junior and I am a girl))))) May  be i have some problems with Promise.all?

Comment: I cant understand why url s (I have success with getting them from firebase) doesnt  fall to Promise all result

Comment: If the problem only occurs outside of `handleUploadProductPhoto`, please edit your question to show where it occurs. It's most likely we can help if you show us the minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem, and then point out exact what line is giving the unexpected result (hence my comment on whether it's the `console.log(res)`).

Comment: Yes, at the bottom i received in then((res) => console.log(res) [undefined, undefined]);

Comment: Also firstly I receive the result of Promise.All in then block (.then((res) => console.log(res))and only after that I Receive my url 
in every Promise. So Promise.all executes before I have result of nested Promise

Comment: Thanks for that last comment. I think I spotted the problem, and will write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `return` on your `new Promise`. So it should be:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ...
```

Without that `return`, each `files.map((file) => {` returns nothing (so `undefined`) and that is what `Promise.all` then passes into your `then`.

Comment: You are a super star!!! It works)))) My stupid error)) Thanks

Comment: Good to hear that was it. And nothing stupid about it. It took me a while to spot it too. :)